# Как можно передать заполненные данные в модальное окно Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

На сайте есть форма: всплывающий список (select), и ползунок (range). После нажатия "Заказать", нужно передать заполненные данные в модальное окно.

С помощью обычного bootstrap окна заполненные данные сбрасываются. С помощью плагина Popup Maker не получилось. Как это можно реализовать?

Пример функционала:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно реализовать при помощи JS, не совсем понятно, каким образом бутстрап и попап мейкер помогают с заполнением полей формы.

Comment: У тебя 2х шагововая форма. Одна форма! Понимание этого факта может помочь решить задачу

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вариант решения будет не один, но мне сразу в голову пришло использовать куки. Предпочтительно их собирать с полей при клике, но так как не знаю всей логики работы, то можно назначить сбор данных и запись их в куки при наведении на кнопку заказать.
Ну и далее записывать их во вторую форму.
Подробнее о куках тут:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie